# How can i add an Nvidia GPU to my 2 Radeon GPUs

Tags: dual-gpu

I guess I'll start with... here's my setup
Cooler Master HAF 932, Asrock Z87 OC Formula/ac, 4770K@4.4GHz, Corsair H80i CPU Cooler,
32GB Gskill RipjawsX 2133MHz,
EVGA Supernova P2 1000W 80+ Platinum Fully Modular PSU,
2x Gigabyte 7870 OC GPU,
4x27" BenQ LED

How can i add an Nvidia GTX 660 GPU to my 2 Radeon GPUs.
Right now nothings happening. I installed the GPU and booted up, tried to install the drivers for the GPU and the installer says "Nvidia GeForce Experience requires an Nvidia GPU. ???
Never had this happen before so I'm not sure how to proceed. Why is it not seeing the new GPU.

Thanks

Comment: It should be as simple as installing the GPU and installing the device drivers.  Please note an application will only be able to use the AMD GPUs or the NVidia GPUs not both at the same time. There are zero games on the market that support the mGPU function within Direct X 12

Comment: Do yourself a favor, DO NOT USE DRIVERPACKS, they are not required.  You can download the .inf via the Nvidia installer directly from Nvidia.  How you do that is simple, use a archive program to grab the correct cab file, then extract the cab file.  [instruction](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/375876/geforce-drivers/why-can-t-i-extract-the-driver-files-/) driver packs ARE EXTREMLY DANGEROUS!

Comment: I had no idea an executable could be extracted like that. Pretty Cool and good to know. I was just using GeForce Experience because I searched for GTX 660 drivers in Google, selected the first one, it said "GeForce GTX 660", the next page, an Nvidia page turned out to be just marketing stuff.

Comment: The driver link takes me to a page that shows "Manual driver search", which doesn't work. "Auto-Detect Your GPU" which also doesn't work. And automatic Driver Updates" Which is the GeForce Experience and also doesn't work. I actually hate these update packages because they're always trying to get you to add crap to your system so I never use them but couldn't find the specific driver for the GTX 660

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean an application won't be able to use the AMD and Nvidia GPUs at the same time. I don't do any gaming. I have mixed GPUs on other machines and they work seamlessly together. You just move from one screen to the next carrying windows and apps from one to the next.

Comment: If you say so.  In the Windows world an application, must know which GPU its going to be used, you can't use Nvidia and AMD GPUs at the sametime.

Answer (score -1):

You can still use a foreign brand, Extra GPU as a multiple monitor hardware acceleration.

You can also use it as a dedicated GPGPU. So long as they are compatible with the same shared APIs like DX10/11/12 etc...

And if not... it will still "work"

### how to install the "weird extra card"

Geforce experience may not work. Because it [checks]

Manual drivers, or "inf" will. Driverpack solutions will do this for you. Thats the easy way.

- https://drp.su/us/

Its safe, but it defaults installing "extra stuff"
Be sure to uncheck all software options, and only have drivers checked

After that, drivers should be updated. The card should run an extra monitor, and add acceleration to webpages, video and games on that monitor.

But I dont think GF experience will work.

in fact last i added an ATI card (amd) the AMD stuff worked, but the NVidia didnt... so who knows.

Comment: Really not sure how to use that driver pack. I downloaded the GPU one and extracted it to a folder. And I have absolutely no idea what to use from in there. There's no inf file in there. There's css, img, js, & Tools folders and a bunch of js files in the root none of which helps me since I don't know what I should do with them. I actually am familiar with the fact that if you rt click on an inf file it has install as one of the options but... There's a start.exe file in the tools but I don't just run executables without knowing what they're going to do and I don't see any explanation of that.

Comment: A gentleman from another site said Nvidia GPUs will not run on less than 8 lanes and since I have 2 GPUs in this system already in slot 1 & 3 the 3rd card would be down to 4 lanes unless I install the Nvidia card in the first slot which stays at 8 lanes with 3 cards. I haven't tried it yet but I will if I can't get the driver to install without GeForce Experience.